# Moving return varibles between Classes

Tags: java, android, variables, android-spinner

I have a method in a Fragment that takes a value from a quantity Spinner and returns it. Where can I retrieve the value of this variable? If I want to move it to a new Activity altogether, how can I retrieve it there?

```
public String SetupQuantitySpinner(String[] quantity) {
    Spinner spnr2;
    spnr2 = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_quantity);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.custom_spinner,
            R.id.text_main_seen,
            quantity);
    spnr2.setAdapter(adapter);
    return quantity[spnr2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
}
```

Basically the Spinner represents the quantity of the item that a user has decided to purchase, i.e. 1 to 20 shirts. I now have to multiply this value by its cost, but the cost is retrieved in another Activity altogether:

```
String cost = currentProduct.getCost();
```

I need to send `quantity[spnr2.getSelectedItemPosition()]` to this new Activity so that I can multiply it by `currentProduct.getCost();`

How can I accomplish this?

**Edit:** This is different and hence not a duplicate because I only want to send and retrieve data associated with the selected Spinner item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to retrieve only selected item in another activity then you can simply put this code inside `onItemSelected` method. And retrieve the value of extra in that activity.

```
String item = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("item",item);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it. Write a global variable:

```
public final static String PRODUCT_SIZE_MESSAGE = "com.elgami.customizer.PRODUCT_SIZE";
```

Start your Intent where you want to in your code:

```
Intent intent;
intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PRODUCT_QUANTITY_MESSAGE, productQuantity);
startActivity(intent);
```

You put the variable you want to send along with your Intent in the Extra, and then retrieve it in the new Class as follows:

```
private int getIntentMessageProductQuantity() {
    return getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.PRODUCT_QUANTITY_MESSAGE, 0);
}
```

Now you have that variable and you can use it as a parameter in any method in the new Class, like so:

```
public void LaunchPurchaseIntent(MainActivity.ProductType productType, int productSize, int productQuantity, String uuid) throws ParseException {
    // Do what you want here

}
```